# Using previous page array values in php into another page

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach, isset

I am creating a online webstore. But i am stuck in calling out the selected value to be used on the next  page.

My Product summary page code,

```html
        <?php
        include 'productData.php';


        if (isset($_GET['cat']) && isset($productArr[$_GET['cat']])) {
            $selected = $productArr[$_GET['cat']];
        }
        foreach ($selected as $productName => $productDescriptionArr):
            ?>

            <div>
                
                <div>

                    <a class="thumbnail" href="productDetailPage.php?cat=<?= $selected; ?>&code=<?= $productName; ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo "img/" . $productDescriptionArr['image'] ?>" class="img-rounded" width="250" height="220">
                        <div><h3><?php echo $productName; ?></h3></div>
                    </a>
                    
                </div>
                
            </div>

        <?php endforeach; ?> 
        

    </body>
</html>
```

My Product Detail Page,

```html
<html>
    
    <body> 

        <?php
        include 'productData.php';
        
       if (isset($_GET['cat']) && isset($productArr[$_GET['cat']])) {
            $selected = $productArr[$_GET['cat']];
            if (isset($_GET['code']) && isset($productName[$_GET['code']])){
                $name = $productName[$_GET['code']];
            }
        }
        foreach ($selected as $name => $productDescriptionArr):
            foreach ($productDescriptionArr as $key => $value) :
            
            ?>

            <div>

                <div>

                        <img src="<?php echo "img/" . $productDescriptionArr['image'] ?>" class="img-rounded" width="250" height="220">
                        <div class="title"><h3><?php echo $name; ?></h3></div>
                    </a>

                </div>

            </div>

        <?php endforeach; ?> 
        <?php endforeach; ?> 


    </body>
</html>
```

in sort, select "PT", moves to page with all "PT" product, and end at the specific selected "PT" product in the product detail page.

Comment: so currently, Are you able to see product summary page, on base of selected category?

Comment: yup yup, the only problem i am facing now is, i do not know how to make it appear on the product detail page.

Comment: ok.. what do you get on your product detail page for `$productName[$_GET['code']]`?

Comment: undefined variable: productName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited your code for product detail page.. As you've not defined $productName variable anywhere in page. I've customized your code and hope it'll be good for you..

```
include 'productData.php';



       <?php

         if (isset($_GET['cat']) && isset($productArr[$_GET['cat']])) {
            $productNames = $productArr[$_GET['cat']];   //Added $productNames here to asign your current product category
        }

          foreach($productNames as $name=>$details): 
            if (isset($_GET['code']) && $name==$_GET['code']){

            //$name is product name.
            //print_r($details);
            // now you can use $details['images'], $details['dimension'], $details['price'] as you want...
          ?>

            <div class="category">

                <div class="col-md-3">

                    <a class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="<?php echo "img/" . $details['image'] ?>" class="img-rounded" width="250" height="220">
                        <div class="title"><h3><?php echo $name; ?></h3></div>
                    </a>

                </div>

            </div>

        <?php } ?> 
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: i gotten this very long URL  /productDetailPage.php?cat=<br%20/><b>Notice</b>:%20%20Array%20to%20string%20conversion%20in%20<b>C:\Program%20Files%20(x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\Assignment1\Assigment01\productSummaryPage.php</b>%20on%20line%20<b>32</b><br%20/>Array&code=IceCream

Comment: Please check your ProductSummary page.. `<a class="thumbnail" href="productDetailPage.php?cat=<?= $selected; ?>&code=<?= $productName; ?>">` in this line `cat=<?=$_GET['cat'];?>`

Comment: It should be `<a class="thumbnail" href="productDetailPage.php?cat=<?= $_GET['cat']; ?>&code=<?= $productName; ?>">`

Comment: it return me, Warning: Illegal string offset 'Giraffe' on line 26---if (isset($_GET['code']) && $key[$_GET['code']]){

Comment: it will be.. please see code, I've mentioned `$key==$_GET['code']` currently I've edited my answer and replaced `$key` with `$name` so you can understand what variable carries..